# Composer exception: Package is already installed

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, composer

After update to new release version [Magento Hackathon](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer/releases)  faced with exception  while running `composer update`: `Package: "some_package_name" is already installed`.
This happened only with this release.

If I set version for example for `1.*` everything is ok.

Has anyone faced with this, any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sergio, that release is a little old and has been officially deprecated according to the project's README :

> **IMPORTANT**
>   This repository is DEPRECATED
>
> Main Development now does happen at https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer
>   The Issues and PRs done here will not be forgotten.
>   If you correctly use this package via packages.firegento.com you have nothing to do

A quick check on the new Cotya project indicates that the latest branch is tagged as [Release 3.0.2](https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer/releases), though it is failing one build test while I'm writing this now.  Version 3.0 was released about a month ago, and contains quite a few fixes since the 2.1.1 release that seems to be causing your problems.

If you

1. Deleted the vendor/composer directory and its contents
2. Replaced your current version from the old Hackathon repo with the latest supported branch (the most recent commits may not be ready yet but something between 2.1.1 - 3.0.2 should be ok) you should get rid of the composer error that's bothering you now.

Comment: Happy to help!  I've only started digging into composer & magento relatively recently (since we started doing more 1.9.X deployments) so I'm keen to see how it interacts with older Magento versions!

Comment: Checked on version 2.1 and 3.0.2, also just put *, still the same error(Magento enterprise)

Comment: So, after I deleted vendor/composer directory, it rebuild and everything is ok now(with all versions), so add this to your question and I'll accept it.